# Oracle set lock timeout for session

Tags: oracle, jdbc

In my java application I want to set the lock timeout in the jdbc connection to an oracle database. When a table is locked actually, my application does not timeout when a lock could not be required. Is there a way to set a timeout?

Comment: There is session parameter called ddl_lock_timeout maybe this is what you need... But it 's used specifically (as name suggest) when one session wants to modify table.

Comment: It would probably be useful to find out why you're acquiring and/or holding locks you don't need. What is locking the table, and what is waiting for the lock? (Not sure why DDL is being assumed...) In the meantime maybe [the resource manager](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dbrm.htm) can help, via MAX_IDLE_BLOCKER_TIME?

Comment: You usually specify that when requesting the lock: `select ... for update wait 10`  to wait 10 seconds for the lock.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Answer is fine, but it would be more helpful to have this option in `update` command as well. It's very often not considered by developers to do the `select ... for update` in advance just to check for a lock. Having an option similar to `ddl_lock_timeout` would make it simpler